# Java - How to create hashmap which holds muliple values for a singe key?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I am making an activity program which stores activities. Basically i have an arrayList of activity objects and each of them have titles. I want to parse the title and assosciate each word from that title with that activities key. For example if there are the following activities:

1)Football game
2)Basketball game
3)Ping pong

Now i want to parse each of those activities, so that for example for the first activity the word football and the word game will be associated with key 1. So if i perform a search using the word "game", the results will be 1 and 2.

I know I can use hash maps and arraylists to implement this but im really not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Map<K, ArrayList<V>> map = new HashMap<>();

Comment: You're looking for a multimap...